# How to display battery percentage on Watch Face

Tags: android-studio, wear-os, moto-360

I am making a new watch face using the official API and I'm trying to figure out how to display battery percentage. (sorry i'm a complete noob)

Comment: What part is the issue? Getting the battery information or displaying it? Your question is fairly broad at the moment.

Comment: I don''t know how to get or display the battery information.

Answer (score 5):

Register a `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` `BroadcastReceiver` inside your `WatchFaceService.Engine.onCreate` override and deregister it in `WatchFaceService.Engine.onDestroy`. When your receive a broadcast, get the battery level from the broadcast, assign it to some field in your watch face and redraw the watch face using the new value.

If this is confusing and you need more detailed description, best build understanding of two areas: watch faces in general and battery monitoring.

To understand watch faces, please follow https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/index.html
It will walk you through the whole process of creating the watch face, including the lifecycle. This will make `onCreate` and `onDestroy` clear.

After you understand watch faces, please read about battery level monitoring on Android: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

After you finish these two pieces, you should actually not need to come back to this question, because things should just come together on their own.

Comment: Is there some code to illustrate this for someone who has never done anything like this before?

Comment: I expanded my answer to point you to documentation that will help you if  you haven't done this before.

Comment: @gruszczy Thanks!! It works perfectly! Is there a similar solution for a network level?

Comment: @AndrewGinnes I wish I could help, but I haven't worked on Wear since 2015, so I don't remember much now ;-)